# How do I fixed my Application Error in Heroku?

Tags: heroku

I can't connect to Heroku due to the following error. I've tried to add a Start script and also a Procfile but it doesn't work. Could someone explan why it doesn't work? I want to know if the error comes from my Github code or from Heroku setup....................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

```
Process exited with status 1
2022-08-12T18:36:39.406029+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-08-12T18:45:08.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user 
2022-08-12T18:45:15.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build output: https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/3beda483-c8d1-40cb-8452-be76a4a2cd04/activity/builds/c4695503-5efb-4c98-a5df-c3e54b7f6e96
2022-08-12T18:46:24.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user 
2022-08-12T18:46:32.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build output: https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/3beda483-c8d1-40cb-8452-be76a4a2cd04/activity/builds/2ebbd773-8c1e-44d1-8601-2ddd3d37eabc
2022-08-12T18:49:19.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user 
2022-08-12T18:49:43.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2022-08-12T18:49:43.145401+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 5fd7082c by user 
2022-08-12T18:49:43.145401+00:00 app[api]: Release v21 created by user 
2022-08-12T18:49:43.554237+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-08-12T18:49:45.494798+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2022-08-12T18:49:47.212235+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-08-12T18:49:47.212248+00:00 app[web.1]: > backend@1.0.0 start
2022-08-12T18:49:47.212248+00:00 app[web.1]: > nodemon backend.js
2022-08-12T18:49:47.212249+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-08-12T18:49:47.219072+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: nodemon: not found
2022-08-12T18:49:47.352457+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2022-08-12T18:49:47.471871+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-08-12T18:49:47.478535+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-08-12T18:49:49.253068+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2022-08-12T18:49:50.192669+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-08-12T18:49:50.192679+00:00 app[web.1]: > backend@1.0.0 start
2022-08-12T18:49:50.192680+00:00 app[web.1]: > nodemon backend.js
2022-08-12T18:49:50.192680+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-08-12T18:49:50.198539+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: nodemon: not found
2022-08-12T18:49:50.322132+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2022-08-12T18:49:50.373383+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-08-12T18:51:02.066411+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=skiplagged-api.herokuapp.com request_id=a15b411f-0fd7-48b8-92e9-329d3596b36a fwd="98.59.250.254" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-08-12T18:51:02.487274+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=skiplagged-api.herokuapp.com request_id=a2eec186-47af-48d6-bc53-d5da65817a56 fwd="98.59.250.254" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-08-12T18:51:33.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user nemail1000@gmail.com
2022-08-12T18:51:48.363071+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=skiplagged-api.herokuapp.com request_id=b9c98980-0f0f-4fa2-9f3c-8f3bd7384e1f fwd="98.59.250.254" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-08-12T18:51:48.697969+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=skiplagged-api.herokuapp.com request_id=16f119c3-71a6-47bf-b759-3a77aaaa9433 fwd="98.59.250.254" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-08-12T18:51:54.720024+00:00 app[api]: Deploy b124ba5b by user nemail1000@gmail.com
2022-08-12T18:51:54.720024+00:00 app[api]: Release v22 created by user nemail1000@gmail.com
2022-08-12T18:51:55.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2022-08-12T18:51:56.660839+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-08-12T18:51:58.872145+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2022-08-12T18:52:01.047678+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-08-12T18:52:01.047692+00:00 app[web.1]: > backend@1.0.0 start
2022-08-12T18:52:01.047693+00:00 app[web.1]: > node backend.js
2022-08-12T18:52:01.047693+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-08-12T18:52:01.116857+00:00 app[web.1]: node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
2022-08-12T18:52:01.116859+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2022-08-12T18:52:01.116859+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2022-08-12T18:52:01.116860+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-08-12T18:52:01.116860+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'express'
2022-08-12T18:52:01.116860+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2022-08-12T18:52:01.116861+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/backend.js
2022-08-12T18:52:01.116862+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
2022-08-12T18:52:01.116862+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27) 
2022-08-12T18:52:01.116863+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)       
2022-08-12T18:52:01.116863+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
2022-08-12T18:52:01.116864+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/backend.js:1:17)
2022-08-12T18:52:01.116866+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)      
2022-08-12T18:52:01.116866+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
2022-08-12T18:52:01.116866+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
2022-08-12T18:52:01.116867+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12) 
2022-08-12T18:52:01.116867+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12) {
2022-08-12T18:52:01.116867+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2022-08-12T18:52:01.116867+00:00 app[web.1]: requireStack: [ '/app/backend.js' ]
2022-08-12T18:52:01.116868+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2022-08-12T18:52:01.263649+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-08-12T18:52:01.549276+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-08-12T18:52:37.125830+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=skiplagged-api.herokuapp.com request_id=fca52976-99a7-4842-be30-c22db8173b0c fwd="98.59.250.254" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-08-12T18:52:37.459549+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=skiplagged-api.herokuapp.com request_id=a2a5fd43-005c-4bd2-9837-522dd9c5764c fwd="98.59.250.254" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-08-12T18:55:48.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user nemail1000@gmail.com
2022-08-12T18:56:14.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2022-08-12T18:56:14.195930+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 0cf3fee6 by user nemail1000@gmail.com
2022-08-12T18:56:14.195930+00:00 app[api]: Release v23 created by user nemail1000@gmail.com
2022-08-12T18:56:14.485780+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-08-12T18:56:16.270776+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2022-08-12T18:56:17.888804+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-08-12T18:56:17.888819+00:00 app[web.1]: > backend@1.0.0 start
2022-08-12T18:56:17.888819+00:00 app[web.1]: > node backend.js
2022-08-12T18:56:17.888819+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-08-12T18:56:17.936917+00:00 app[web.1]: node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
2022-08-12T18:56:17.936918+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2022-08-12T18:56:17.936918+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2022-08-12T18:56:17.936919+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-08-12T18:56:17.936919+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'express'
2022-08-12T18:56:17.936919+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2022-08-12T18:56:17.936920+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/backend.js
2022-08-12T18:56:17.936921+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
2022-08-12T18:56:17.936921+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27) 
2022-08-12T18:56:17.936921+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)       
2022-08-12T18:56:17.936922+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
2022-08-12T18:56:17.936922+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/backend.js:1:17)
2022-08-12T18:56:17.936923+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)      
2022-08-12T18:56:17.936923+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
2022-08-12T18:56:17.936924+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
2022-08-12T18:56:17.936924+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12) 
2022-08-12T18:56:17.936924+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12) {
2022-08-12T18:56:17.936925+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2022-08-12T18:56:17.936925+00:00 app[web.1]: requireStack: [ '/app/backend.js' ]
2022-08-12T18:56:17.936925+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2022-08-12T18:56:18.056972+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-08-12T18:56:18.132643+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-08-12T18:58:17.391471+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=skiplagged-api.herokuapp.com request_id=7f7134e2-6177-44c1-911f-2f427d03a84f fwd="98.59.250.254" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-08-12T18:58:17.797623+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=skiplagged-api.herokuapp.com request_id=771f6d92-ccc4-4495-a5b8-9d87cdb81903 fwd="98.59.250.254" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Procfile:
[Procfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BX2SW.png)

Package.json:
[Package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqOvc.png)

New error From the Comment:[Second Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9082Q.png)

[Heroku Buildpacks and Config Vars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9dl2.png)

Comment: You are trying to run `nodemon` on Heroku, but you shouldn't be. That is a _development_ tool, not something that should be used in production. "I've tried to add a Start script and also a Procfile but it doesn't work. Could someone explan why it doesn't work?"—we can't tell you much more than I just did without actually _seeing_ the `Procfile` and `package.json`. "I added those files" tells us virtually nothing.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add those files as code blocks. Same with the error output. It is very hard to read that kind of thing in a comment.

Comment: Question edited. I've added the Procfile, Package.json and the error message.

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.